# Why is my app failing to find a user during authentication?

Tags: if-statement, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I've had a problem on and off for the past week where my else statement is executing in the MainTabView upon login/signup (meaning it can't find the currentuser??) So rather than logging in and showing the main navigation, I see a white "loading.." screen after logging in. It's odd cause some log in's have worked fine and others crash the app. Any help is very appreciated!

I don't think the problem is within EmailAuth or CreateAccountAuth but let me know if you'd like to see the code for those too.

**AuthViewModel:**

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

class AuthViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var userSession: FirebaseAuth.User?
    @Published var currentUser: User?
    @Published var selectedImage: UIImage?
    
    private let service = UserService()
        
    static let shared = AuthViewModel()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        userSession = Auth.auth().currentUser
        
        fetchUser()
    }
    
    func login(withEmail email: String, password: String) {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("DEBUG: Failed to sign in with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            self.userSession = result?.user
            self.fetchUser()
        }
    }
    
    func register(withEmail email: String, password: String, fullname: String) {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("DEBUG: Failed to register with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let user = result?.user else { return }
            self.userSession = user

            let data: [String: Any] = ["email": email,
                                       "fullname": fullname]
            
            COLLECTION_USERS
                .document(user.uid)
                .setData(data)
            self.uploadProfileImage(self.selectedImage)
        }
    }
    
    func signOut() {
        // sets user session to nil so we show login view
        self.userSession = nil
        
        // signs user out on server
        try? Auth.auth().signOut()
    }
    
    func uploadProfileImage(_ image: UIImage?) {
        guard let uid = userSession?.uid else { return }
        
        ImageUploader.uploadImage(image: image) { profileImageUrl in
            COLLECTION_USERS
                .document(uid)
                .updateData(["profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl])
            //{ _ in self.userSession = user }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchUser() {
        guard let uid = userSession?.uid else { return }
        
        COLLECTION_USERS.document(uid).getDocument { snapshot, _ in
            guard let user = try? snapshot?.data(as: User.self) else { return }
            self.currentUser = user
        }
    }
}
```

**App File:**

```
struct Page_TurnerApp: App {
    
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ContentView().environmentObject(AuthViewModel())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ContentView**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if viewModel.userSession != nil {
                MainTabView()
            } else {
                EmailAuth()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**MainTabView**

```
struct MainTabView: View {
    @State private var selectedIndex = 0
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        if let user = viewModel.currentUser {
            TabView(selection: $selectedIndex) {
                ExploreView()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.selectedIndex = 0
                    }
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "house")
                    }.tag(0)
                
                SearchView()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.selectedIndex = 1
                    }
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                    }.tag(1)
                
                ConversationsView()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.selectedIndex = 2
                    }
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "message")
                    }.tag(2)
                
                AccountView(user: user)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.selectedIndex = 3
                    }
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                    }.tag(3)
            }
        } else {
            Text("loading...")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `AuthViewModel` is an `ObservableObject` in your `Page_TurnerApp`,  you could try using `@StateObject var viewModel = AuthViewModel()` and passing this to the `.environmentObject(viewModel)`.
Did my comment (related to `@StateObject`) to your previous question worked?

Comment: Thanks! Adding the @StateObject did not work for either problem, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that my User wasn't being created unless there was a profile image. That's why it worked for certain users and crashed for others. I changed  `let profileImageUrl: String`
to  `let profileImageUrl: String?` and all users can log in now

Comment: Exactly ! in this case you should use a optional type
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/optional-types-in-swift/